# Can't open Unicode URL with Python

Tags: python, unicode

Using Python 2.5.2 and Linux Debian, I'm trying to get the content from a Spanish URL that contains a Spanish char `'í'`:

```
import urllib
url = u'http://mydomain.es/índice.html'
content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

I'm getting this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

I've tried using before passing the url to urllib this:

```
url = urllib.quote(url)
```

and this:

```
url = url.encode('UTF-8')
```

but they didn't work.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the applicable standard, [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html), URLs can only contain ASCII characters. Good explanation [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), and I quote:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z],
> the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),"
> [not including the quotes - ed], and
> reserved characters used for their
> reserved purposes may be used
> unencoded within a URL."

As the URLs I've given explain, this probably means you'll have to replace that "lowercase i with acute accent" with `%ED'.

Comment: I believe this has since been changed, and at least domains can now contain arbitrary Unicode characters.

Comment: @Cerin Sort of. [IRIs can contain arbitrary Unicode characters](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri), but when you convert them to regular URIs they're normalised to ASCII using 'Punycode' (for the domain component) and percent-encoding (for the path component).

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# define source file encoding, see: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib
url = u'http://example.com/índice.html'
content = urllib.urlopen(url.encode("UTF-8")).read()
```

Answer (score 4):

Encoding the URL as utf-8, should have worked. I wonder if your source file is properly encoded, and whether the interpreter knows it. If your python source file is saved as UTF-8, for example, then you should have

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

as the first or second line.

```
import urllib
url = u'http://mydomain.es/índice.html'
content = urllib.urlopen(url.encode('utf-8')).read()
```

works for me.

Edit: also, be aware that Unicode text in an interactive Python session (whether through IDLE, or a console) is fraught with encoding-related difficulty. In those cases, you should use Unicode literals (like \u00ED in your case).

Answer (score 3):

It works for me. Make sure you're using a fairly recent version of Python, and your file encoding is correct.
Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
url = u'http://mydomain.es/índice.html'
url = url.encode('utf-8')
content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

(mydomain.es does not exist, so the DNS lookup fails, but there are no unicode issues to that point.)

Comment: With python 3 I get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'` when using this code. Is there a python 3 solution?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson You should try: `urllib.parse.quote(url)` instead of `url.encode('utf-8')`
You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar case, right now. I'm trying to download images. I retrieve the URLs from the server in a JSON file. Some of the images contain non-ASCII characters. This throws an error:

```
for image in product["images"]: 
    filename = os.path.basename(image) 
    filepath = product_path + "/" + filename 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, filepath) # error!
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc7' in position ...

---

I've tried using `.encode("UTF-8")`, but can't say it helped:

```
# coding=UTF-8
import urllib
url = u"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/İMAGE-1.png"
url = url.encode("UTF-8")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "D:\image-1.jpg")
```

This just throws another error:

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

---

Then I gave `urllib.parse.quote(url)` a go:

```
import urllib
url = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/İMAGE-1.png"
url = urllib.parse.quote(url)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "D:\image-1.jpg")
```

and again, this throws another error:

> ValueError: unknown url type: 'http%3A//example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/%C4%B0MAGE-1.png'

The `:` in `"http://..."` also got escaped, and I think this is the cause of the problem.

So, I've figured out a workaround. I just quote/escape the path, not the whole URL.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/İMAGE-1.png"
url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
url = url.scheme + "://" + url.netloc + urllib.parse.quote(url.path)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "D:\image-1.jpg")
```

This is what the URL looks like: `"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/%C4%B0MAGE-1.png"`, and now I can download the image.