# apply_filters() function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

hey guys im really frustrated

im looking for a way to retrieve back  my slug to the normal text as  wordpress does

in wordpress there is a function to do so :

apply_filters('editable_slug', $slug)

i search all related files to find what this function does, but couldn't understand a bit.

as ypu may know , making a slug out of a normal text is a easy job , but when its converted ,  for Utf-8 languages such as Arabic , words will be changed to  unreadable unicodes .

e.g.  :

http://localhost/page/%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%84%d9%87

do you know how this function works in wordpress ?

apply_filters('editable_slug', $slug)

and how i can do the same in my own php project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call rawurldecode on the percent-encoded form -- this will give you the text in UTF-8 encoding. If your webpage encoding is UTF-8, you just have to call htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8').

Example:

```
$str = rawurldecode('%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%84%d9%87');
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: thanks i took your advice and i got an error :

htmlspecialchars($slug, ENT_NO_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in...

Comment: sorry, it put an extra underscore. However, after reading the discussion in Pekka's answer, I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: OK, I apparently I did :p Don't forget to call htmlspecialchars!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question: [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls) for some good background.

The URL you show looks okay basically - it's the proper percent encoded representation of the arabic characters in question.

You should be able to display them in proper arabic on your web page. Copy+pasting will give you the URLencoded form, which is a good thing because that way, your permalinks will work in non-UTF-8-speaking clients as well.

Comment: thanks but i need to show them in table columns , not in my address bar , hope you understand that , and that's why wordpress uses that function

Comment: @Mac Taylor the characters should turn up as proper arabic in your page. Can you show a live example?

Comment: i did , and its there in my question post :( 
again : http://localhost/page/%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%84%d9%87
u cant see these unidefined characters after page/ ? it should be like this  الله  not %d8%a7%d9%84%d9%84%d9%87 , wordpress uses apply_filter to solve this problem

Comment: @Mac I see. They are not undefined characters, but the percent encoded representation of the arabic literals. Hmm... `urldecode()` would probably be the solution but I don't know how to get that into the Wordpress filtering thingy, sorry.