# How to use german umlaute in rails3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

really big problem
example request

[http://localhost:3000/freund/in/münchen](http://localhost:3000/freund/in/m%C3%BCnchen)

my first route in routes.rb

```
match ':category/in/:city' => 'home#index', :constraints => {:city => /(berlin|hamburg|münchen)/ }
```

and I get the error
Routing Error

No route matches "/freund/in/m%C3%BCnchen"

what can I do? I postet everywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

"Real" Unicode characters in URLs are invalid. They usually get percent encoded by the browser, which results in `m%C3%BCnchen`. You will need to check for that inside Ruby.

This question provides more background: [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: thanks pekka, 
i found a workaround for my issue. It's not the prettiest, but I left out the constraints part and do the "validation" check in the controller (grabbing params) this seems to work really great :)

Comment: @tabaluga yeah, the input probably gets unescaped before entering the controller. Probably more convenient that way.

Comment: By the way, your list of major german cities is blatantly incomplete! (*Ahem*)