# Valid link with GET parameters

Tags: xhtml

How can i place valid link with get parameters into my page?

When i run validator, it gives error:

```
Line 37, Column 37: reference to entity "p" for which no system identifier could be generated
<li><a href="index.php?c=tutorials&p=cat&cid=1" >LINK</a></li>
```

Comment: **Related:** *(Same question tagged as 'HTML')* [Do I encode ampersands in <a href…>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3705591/1497596)

Comment: @DavidRR Not the same question... similar, but different question. He's asking whether ampersands should be encoded. I'm asking why is it wrong in validator ( didn't know about ampersand encoding, so I didn't know I have to search something about encoding )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from here
http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Code_Validation

The most common error by far looks something like this:
reference to entity "BV_Engine" for which no system identifier could be generated.
What that means is simply that you've got a URL with an & sign in it that you forgot to escape.

For example:
 `<a href="script.cgi?id=4&BV_Engine=20">`

The & sign in this URL should be &. In fact ALL & signs in an HTML document should be escaped in this way to avoid causing confusion to HTML parsers. For the above example, replacing it with

```
<a href="script.cgi?id=4&amp;BV_Engine=20">
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape your ampersands:

```
<li><a href="index.php?c=tutorials&amp;p=cat&amp;cid=1" >LINK</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use & instead of plain &. Its an html entity.

```
<li><a href="index.php?c=tutorials&amp;p=cat&amp;cid=1" >LINK</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed it is as we have posted the same thing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the others have posted above, you need to escape your amparsands as &amp; rather than &.

```
<li><a href="index.php?c=tutorials&amp;p=cat&amp;cid=1">LINK</a></li>
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

To be compatible with **XHTML** (and **XML** in general), the [ampersand](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26/index.htm) **must** be escaped. To do so requires the use of an [SGML/XML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_entity).

There are three different entities that can be used to represent the ampersand:

1. Named entity: `&amp;` *(This is one of the five [predefined entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) defined in the XML specification.)*
2. Decimal [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference): `&#38;`
3. Hexadecimal [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference): `&#x26;`

So, the value of your example `href` attribute could be represented in one of these three ways:

```
href="index.php?c=tutorials&amp;p=cat&amp;cid=1"
href="index.php?c=tutorials&#38;p=cat&#38;cid=1"
href="index.php?c=tutorials&#x26;p=cat&#x26;cid=1"
```

Of course, it would be valid to mix the above entities like this:

```
href="index.php?c=tutorials&amp;p=cat&#38;cid=1"
                           ^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

...but most would argue for taking a consistent approach throughout a document (and even an entire web site).

Of the three entities that can be used to represent the ampersand, I believe that `&amp;` is used most commonly in XHTML.

**Final note:** One of the above entities *should* also be used when authoring **HTML**, however [browsers today do not require that the ampersand be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16455004/1497596).