# Why doesn't Twitter and Google API documentation encode ampersands in URLs?

Tags: html, url, cross-browser, html-entities

I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href) I should encode my ampersands as `&amp;` in HTML.
However **numerous** code samples from respected companies somehow **forget to do this**.

Just a few examples off the top of my head:

[Google Web Fonts](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Subsets) sample code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

[Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization) documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
```

[Twitter Anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#getting-started) official tutorial:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there any real benefit from *not* escaping ampersand in links?
Is this related to browser quirks? Is this just a mistake in documentation?

> **Dear answerers, please make sure you're answering the *right* question.**
>
> I know I **should** escape ampersands per spec. I also know **why** the mechanism was invented in the first place. I'm not [asking about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href). My question is:
>
> **Is there *a reason* API documentation by respectable companies often violates this rule?**

Comment: Answerers, please note that they are not doing this because it's correct. Failing to encode the ampersands actually violates the [HTML 4.1 specification, section 5.3.2:  Character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.2): *Authors should use "&amp;" (ASCII decimal 38) instead of "&" to avoid confusion with the beginning of a character reference (entity reference open delimiter). **Authors should also use "&amp;" in attribute values since character references are allowed within CDATA attribute values.***

Comment: Dan, I realize you already linked to a question about that in your post, but the current answerers seem to have missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any real benefit from not escaping ampersand in links?

It saves a few keystrokes.

> Is this related to browser quirks?

No

> Is this just a mistake in documentation?

Yes

> Is there a reason API documentation by respectable companies often violates this rule?

Ignorance and/or laziness. Browsers perform error recovery so they either don't notice the errors or they don't care. The documentation probably isn't written by their best experts.

Answer (score 5):

Two different contexts here.

1. Within the context of a javascript href, the & is just fine and should not be encoded.
2. In an HTML link the & is forbidden and should be escaped.

In the HTML link context an HTML character entity will be decoded before the address is passed to the HTTP process; a URL-encoded character will not, as the server can read it directly.