# W3 validator errors in Magento 1.7.0.2 header

Tags: html, seo, w3c-validation

I am validating my store in W3 validator and I am gettin some errors in this line:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,700,400&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

The problem seem to lie in `&subset=` code.

The w3 validator returns:

> An entity reference was found in the document, but there is no
>   reference by that name defined. Often this is caused by misspelling
>   the reference name, unencoded ampersands, or by leaving off the
>   trailing semicolon (;). The most common cause of this error is
>   unencoded ampersands in URLs as described by the WDG in "Ampersands in
>   URLs".
>
> Entity references start with an ampersand (&) and end with a semicolon
>   (;). If you want to use a literal ampersand in your document you must
>   encode it as "&" (even inside URLs!). Be careful to end entity
>   references with a semicolon or your entity reference may get
>   interpreted in connection with the following text. Also keep in mind
>   that named entity references are case-sensitive; &Aelig; and æ
>   are different characters.
>
> If this error appears in some markup generated by PHP's session
>   handling code, this article has explanations and solutions to your
>   problem.
>
> Note that in most documents, errors related to entity references will
>   trigger up to 5 separate messages from the Validator. Usually these
>   will all disappear when the original problem is fixed.

I have four questions:

- where is this line generated? I cant seem to find it.
- what is the correct syntax for it?
- is meta `name="keywords"` tag obsolete? I think so, but even the newest magento version still auto generates it. Can it be removed?
- i would like to add custom SEO stuff in header. What would be the correct location for it, since the header parses from multiple locations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: dty I am still editing :) you guys are too fast :)

Comment: What can I tell you? :-)

Comment: Have you tried with `&amp;subset=` instead of `&subset=`?

Comment: You should create (or search for) separate questions for your other questions regarding `keywords` and SEO.

Comment: agreed. Also thanx to sp00m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode `&` in links. See for example the question: [Do I encode ampersands in <a href...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705591/1591669)

So `&` should become `&amp;` (as long as you don't want to reference a different entity).

Comment: thanks for the anwser Unor. I somehow got that from the error myself but wasnt sure. Now i need to find the location where this happens in magento core...

Comment: @no9: I don't know Magento, but I'd guess it happens in a theme (as this `link` element adds a CSS file). Maybe this helps: [How do I add Google Font CSS to page.xml or catalog.xml](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/392684/) and [How To: Use Google Fonts on Your Magento Store](http://www.howtoinstallmagento.com/google-fonts-magento-store/)