# HTML SMS message body. Everything after & symbol disappears

Tags: android, html, sms

I'm currently developing a web app and there is this part of the code where I have to pre-populate the message in the sms box. So my code looks like this:

```
    <a href="sms:?body=This is the message with & symbol">SMS</a>
```

In the pre-populated message, everything from the & symbol onwards does not appear in the message box on the phone. I know I have to encode it but I do not know what the encoding code is. Any solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: Even in 2017 this is still a problem. I think this question just hasn't garnered much attention because it's decently obscure; I get the feeling not many people generating links with the `sms:` protocol like this. Did you ever find a solution? We ended up just not permitting the `&` symbol in the sms body.

Answer (score 5):

This seems really crazy but encoding the body twice does the trick.

```
<a href="sms:?body=hello & stuff">not encoded (doesn't work)</a>
<a href="sms:?body=hello%20%26%20stuff">uri component encoded (doesn't work)</a>
<a href="sms:?body=hello%2520%2526%2520stuff">double uri component encoded (works fine)</a>
```

Working fiddle to test from an android device: https://jsfiddle.net/k96g2h48/

Comment: Unfortunately, double-encoding will make the body show up as encoded on iOS.

Answer (score 5):

Android and iOS respond to slightly different syntaxes. To put `&`  inside the body of text, iOS needs URL encoding. For Android, it requires double encoding as mentioned in @Crisman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455514/2299040).  check the below code:

```html
<a href="sms:&body=hi%26bye">iOS</a>
<br>
<a href="sms:?body=hello%2520%2526%2520stuff">double uri component encoded (works fine)</a>
```

The first link worked in iOS and the second link works in Android. 
Notice the syntax of both URLs. `&` and `?` with this they with `&` ios distinguish between number and body part whereas `?` is used to separate number and body.

An example with number is like

```html
<a href="sms:123456&body=hi%26bye">iOS</a>
<br>
<a href="sms:123456?body=hello%2520%2526%2520stuff">double uri component encoded (works fine)</a>
```

You can also try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h05k63r/8/)

Comment: Unfortunately the newest Android requires single encoding, and double encoding doesn't work :-(

Comment: @MarkProbst I've tested double encoding on my Android phone based on Android Pie and it's working fine. Model is xiaomi redmi 6 pro

Comment: @MarkProbst what Android versions are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Encode your & character because it has a special meaning in an URL ( it is the separator for fields)

```
<a href="sms:?body=This+is+the+message+with+%26+symbol">SMS</a>
```

The characters that have a special meaning in URL need to be ecnode if you just want there text respresentation.

[wikipedia on percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: I tried this, messages from the & symbol onwards still goes missing.

Comment: On which browser are you trying this? I verfied this in Opera on win2k8 with Outlook as client (used mailto:?body=bar%26foo) and that works

Comment: i'm using the phone to go onto the web app with android browser

Comment: are you sure the link doens't get double encoded? I don't have an android phone but can you do something like view source to verify that the html looks like you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&#38;` instead of "&" as this is the ASCII version of the character and used to show up as text in a HTML document

Comment: i just tried this, but still getting the same result. Any message from the & symbol onwards disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write like below

```
  <a href="sms:?body=This is the message with &amp; symbol">SMS</a>
```

Comment: I tried this, I'm still having the same issue as what I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this char `\u0026`?

```
<a href="sms:?body=This is the message with \u0026 symbol">SMS</a>
```

reference from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705601/10989990

**EDIT**

Some browsers will accept `&` and some browsers will not accept this char so everything after `&` will be considered as the query parameter

**EDIT**

may be javascript helps to use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var txt = "SMS";
document.write("<p>" + txt.link("sms:?body=This is the message with & symbol") + "</p>");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck :)