# google maps has unencoded ampersands in urls

Tags: google-maps

I have an embedded map on a page. It won't [W3C validate due](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcalpropertyappraisals.com%2Fcontact.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) to unencoded ampersands in the url for a marker. If I encode the `&` as `&amp;` then it validates but the marker doesn't show up. Is there a solution for this dilemma? I've seen other people that also have this problem, but I not seen any solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I encode ampersands in <a href...>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href)

Comment: can you give an example-URL?

Comment: Here is the page: http://calpropertyappraisals.com/contact.php

Comment: I know I should encode the &, but when I do, it breaks the google maps marker function. it contains this url:
              icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|FF0000|000000'  
          });

Comment: [chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|FF0000|000000](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|FF0000|000000)

Comment: The most obvious (and cleanest) approach would be to move the JavaScript to another file.

Comment: OK, if I wrap the script with the CDATA tags as recommended below, all is well. I'll also try moving the js to a separate file.
Thanks

Comment: I have now separated the js code into its own file and now the map marker works and the page passes the validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) attempting to validate javascript as HTML

Wrap your script in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[


//]]>
</script>
```

If [I do that with your code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_calpropertyappraisals_com_contactA.html), the 
[page validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fv3_SO_calpropertyappraisals_com_contactA.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: That's exactly why I hate the W3C validator.

Comment: It's no problem of the validator. The document is declared as XHTML, and in XHTML the [content of script-element is defined as #PCDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) (parsed character data) . It's simply not valid, and the validator is doing what he has been intended for.