# LXML's etree.tostring escaping urls in link href attributes

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml, elementtree

When using LXML to parse an html document, and then using etree.tostring(), I am noticing that the ampersands in links are being converted to html-escaped entities.

This is breaking the link, for obvious reasons. Here is a simple self-contained example of the problem:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring("""<a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2">link</a>""", parser)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<html><body><a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2">link</a></body></html>'
```

I wish the output would be:

```
<html><body><a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2">link</a></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although & encoding is supposed to be the [standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href). If you really need to avoid conversion for some reasons, then you can do:

**Step 1.** Find an unique string which shouldn't exist in your html source. You can simply use **ANDamp;** as your reserved_amp variable if you confident "ANDamp;" string will not appear in your html source. Otherwise you might consider to generate random alphabetic and check to ensure this string didn't exist in your html source:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> length = 15 #increase the length if it's still seems to be collide
>>> reserved_amp = "&amp;"
>>> html = """<a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2">link</a>"""
>>> while reserved_amp in [html, "&amp;"]: 
...     reserved_amp = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(length)) + "amp;" #amp; is for you easy to spot on
... 
>>> print reserved_amp
2eya6oywxg5z7q5amp;
```

**Step 2.** replace all occurance of & before parse:

```
>>> html = html.replace("&", reserved_amp)
>>> html
'<a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value12eya6oywxg5z7q5amp;param2=value2">link</a>'
>>>
```

**Step 3.** replace it back only if you need the original form:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(html, parser)
>>> etree.tostring(tree).replace(reserved_amp, "&")
'<html><body><a href="https://www.example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2">link</a></body></html>'
>>>
```

**[UPDATE]:**

The colon put at the end of `reserved_amp` is a **safe guard**.

What if we generated a `reserved_amp` like that ?

`ampXampXampXampX + amp;`

And html contains:

`yyYampX&`

It will encoded at this form:

`yyYampXampXampXampXampXamp;`

Still, it's not possible to return/decoded wrong reversed result something like `yy&YampX` (original is `yyYampX&`) due to the **colon** safe guard at the last character is a non-ASCII alphabetical which will never get generated as `reserved_amp` from `string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits` above.

So, ensure the random not using colon(or other non-ASCII character) and then append it at the end(MUST be the last character) will no need to worry about `yyYampX&` revert back to `yy&YampX` pitfall.

Comment: Patching lxml is better than this hack

Answer (score 0):

According to [lxml's tostring() docs](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html-module.html#tostring), `method='xml'` could be passed to avoid html's specifics

```
etree.tostring(tree, method='xml')
```

In my projects I use:

```
from lxml import html
html.tostring(node, with_tail=False, method='xml', encoding='unicode')
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me. I needed to pretty-print an XML tree, but some elements had `&#160;` in their text. Using `stree.tostring(element, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True, method='xml')` I got `&amp#160;`