# Escaping '&' character in thymeleaf

Tags: hyperlink, thymeleaf

I need an image loaded onto a html `img` tag using thymeleaf. The problem is, the image itself is obtained from a url which takes in two parameters.

Sample:

```
<img src="/products/images?categoryId=1&image=1" />
```

The trouble is, the `image` parameter is generated dynamically and hence I need to use a thymeleaf expression there. Therefore I tried something like this:

```
<img th:src="@{'/products/images?categoryId=1&image=' + ${product.id}}" />
```

But when I run this, I get the following message:

```
Exception parsing document: template="product-list", line 104 - column 59
```

Which points to the location where the '&' symbol occurs. Now, I have tried using '& amp;' but then, the url becomes something like

```
/products/images?categoryId=1&amp;image=1
```

Obviously, this is not going to work.

So how else do I make a valid link with two parameters using thymeleaf then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can easily done by Thymeleaf. Don't concatenate strings and
simply use `@{'/products/images'(categoryId=1, image= ${product.id})}`

See the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Guess I didn't know what to search for. I was just searching for ways to get the '&' symbol to show up!

Answer (score 4):

The way that you escape an ampersand `&` in any html attribute is `&amp;`.  Actually you should always escape ampersands in all html attributes whether you are using Thymeleaf or not.

See this question for more details and references:
[Do I encode ampersands in <a href...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href)