# file_get_contents() function loads different page compared to broswer

Tags: php, html, file, browser, hyperlink

I am trying to find next page's link of a particular page(i call that particular page as `current page` here).The `current page`  in program i am using is

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1980_births

The `next page link` which i am extracting from the `current page` is the below one

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:1980_births&pagefrom=Alexis%2C+Toya%0AToya+Alexis#mw-pages

But ,, when file_get_contents() function load the `next page link` it's getting the  the `current page` contents ,,,

The code is

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1980_births");  //Getting contents of current page , 
preg_match_all("/\(previous page\) \(<a href=\"(.*)\" title/",  $string,$matches);    // extracting the next_page_link from the current page contents

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
break;
}

$next_page_link = $match;  
$next_page_link =  "http://en.wikipedia.org" . $next_page_link; //the next_link will have only the path , does't contain the domain name ,,, so i am adding the domain name here, this does't make any impact on the problem statement

$string1 = file_get_contents($next_page_link);
echo $next_page_link;
echo $string1;

?>
```

As per the code `string1` should have `next_page_link's` content ,, but instead it just getting the `current page`'s content.

Comment: Uhm... `foreach ($matches[1] as $match) break;`... Do you mean `$match = $matches[1][0];`?!

Comment: yes correct(i made it complex) ,, we can even remove the break statement ,,, totally that current page has three next page links((all are same page link only) ,,, i am just taking the first one and breaking the loop(just to avoid next 2 iterations),,,

Comment: I don't see any differences on my local test!!

Comment: could you be specific ,, The program should print http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:1980_births&pagefrom=Alexis%2C+Toya%0AToya+Alexis#mw-pages as the result ,, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1980_births this page was loading in the program for me ,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source of the original web site, the links have entity-encoded ampersands (See [Do I encode ampersands in <a href…>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href)). The browser decodes them normally when you click the anchor, but your scraping code does not. Compare

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/ ... &amp;pagefrom=Alexis%2C+Toya%0AToya+Alexis#mw-pages
```

versus

```
http://en.wikipedia.org ... &pagefrom=Alexis%2C+Toya%0AToya+Alexis#mw-pages
```

This malformed querystring is what you are in fact passing into `file_get_contents`. You can convert them back to regular ampersands like this:

```
// $next_page_link = $match; 
$next_page_link = html_entity_decode($match);
```