# How do I disable escaping of a URL (particularly the &) in a Thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm passing a bean `QuoteOption` into the model that has a method called `getCachedImageUrl(url, width, height)` that returns a URL for the image.

*My Thymeleaf template:*

```
<img th:src="${quoteOption.getCachedImageUrl(baseUrl,300,200)}" />
```

*Generates*

```
<img src="http://nitro:8080/image/nitro-resources-development/28f08e67-96c9-4bb4-8012-9e34040cc976.jpeg?width=300&amp;height=200" />
```

Notice the `&amp;` in the url parameters! Aaaargh! How do I instruct Thymeleaf to *not* escape the ampersand?

Comment: That's correct HTML - the & _should_ be escaped as &amp;

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href

Comment: @daiscog, I've been developing web applications for 20 years, and I never knew this. Used thymeleaf to send an email with `&amp;` in the `href` attribute, and it works 100%. Thank you for educating me!

Answer (score 0):

Bean with name `someBean`:

```
public class SomeBean {

       public String testMethod() {
            return "http://nitro:8080/image/nitro-resources-development/28f08e67-96c9-4bb4-8012-9e34040cc976.jpeg?width=300&height=200";
        }
}
```

In Thymeleaf :

```
  <img th:src="${@applicationCache.testMethod()}" id="_Bhuwan"/>
  <button onclick="alert($('#_Bhuwan').attr('src'))">See</button>
```

Two Case :

1. **In alert Show message as :**

   `http://nitro:8080/image/nitro-resources-development/28f08e67-96c9-4bb4-8012-9e34040cc976.jpeg?width=300&height=200`
2. **In View Page Source or Edit HTML in Browser.** Generate :

   `<img src="http://nitro:8080/image/nitro-resources-development/28f08e67-96c9-4bb4-8012-9e34040cc976.jpeg?width=300&amp;height=200">`

So that actual value in src attribute of img tag is `http://nitro:8080/image/nitro-resources-development/28f08e67-96c9-4bb4-8012-9e34040cc976.jpeg?width=300&height=200` in this case. But when we try see value using View Page source or edit html through browser then Browser may escape `&` char to `&amp;`.

**Tested On**
Themeleaf version is `2.1.4.RELEASE` in Spring 4.