# Show Raw text unencoded in Scala Play template

Tags: scala, templates, encoding, playframework

I'm working on a project in Play (+Scala) where after a particular flow, an email is sent.

The email uses a template (e.g. email.scala.html), which contains HTML and inserts data from a "model" (which is really a Map[String, String])

What I find is some text is encoded which I don't want encoded

For example:

```
<a href="http://madeupsite.com?param1=x&param2=y">link</a>
```

Gets encoded like (notice `&` gets replaced with `&amp;`):

```
<a href="http://madeupsite.com?param1=x&amp;param2=y">link</a>
```

This will break the link that gets emailed

How this gets included in the template:

```
<a href="@emailModel.get("url").get">link</a>
```

In code:

```
def prepareEmail(tuple: (Map[String, String], Map[String, String])): HtmlEmail = tuple match {

          case (headers, emailBody) if headers.nonEmpty && emailBody.nonEmpty => {
            def createMessageFromTemplate(model: Map[String, String]): String = {
              views.html.email(model).toString
            }
...
```

This line is the important bit

```
views.html.email(model).toString
```

I can't seem to find anything on rendering this without encoding

For example these don't seem to work:

```
@Html(...)
@TxtFormat.raw(...)
@TxtFormat.raw(...).toString.replace("&amp;", "&")
```

I'm not a Play/Scala expert, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the value of `emailModel.get("url").get`? Is it already escaped?

Comment: Probably `&` should be encoded to `&amp;` within `href=""`. For sure it is the case for `xhtml`;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href . w3 validator has been complaining about unencoded ampersands within attributes.