# Why does flask redirect parse character & to HTML entity &amp; for external URLs?

Tags: python, flask, urlencode

I want to redirect users to an external URL with parameters in a flask application that I've set up, I use `urlencode` like so:

```py
parameters = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux'}
link = 'https://some.domain.com?%s' % urlencode(parameters)
return redirect(link, code=302)
```

If I cUrl my endpoint, let's say `curl https://my.domain.com/endpoint`, it returns a HTML document like so:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to the target URL: <a href="https://some.domain.com?foo=bar&amp;baz=qux">https://some.domain.com?foo=bar&amp;baz=qux</a>. If not, click the link.
```

Note the link being parsed:

```
https://some.domain.com?foo=bar&amp;baz=qux
```

If I simply print the `link` it is properly encoded:

```
https://some.domain.com?foo=bar&baz=qux
```

So why does `redirect` generate this HTML page with `&` characters parsed as HTML entity `&amp;` where it is not required? How can I avoid this?

I am using Python `3.9.2`.

Comment: If you view that HTML document in a web browser, does the link point to the correct location? Does the text of the link display as it should? If this happens (and I strongly suspect it will) then Flask is behaving as expected. `&amp;` is an HTML entity for the ampersand character. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity .

Comment: Yes it does. I was mostly curious about the use of HTML entities in HTML code, here, in the href, not so much in its text representation (the text of the link). Do you know if that is some recommended way of putting ampersands in hrefs?

Comment: Yes, the recommended way to put an ampersand in an href is as `&amp;`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705591).