# how do I properly encode a URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, url-encoding, encodeuricomponent

I am working on a browser plugin that takes the URL of the current page or any selected link as a parameter and send it to our server.
When characters of the basic latin alphabet are present in the url (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle), the plugin works fine. However, when the URL contains characters from another alphabet such as [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коляска](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) the plugin does not work, I do use the `encodeURIComponent`method but that does not seem to solve the issue. Any idea?

Thanks,

Olivier.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коляска is not really a valid URL. When you enter that into a modern browser, it will URLEncode the characters automatically. Can you explain in more detail what you are doing, where the data is coming from, and what `encodeURIComponent` does that doesn't suit? Also, what do you mean by "browser plugin" exactly?

Comment: Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)/[`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI), if you are trying to take a full URI with non-ASCII characters and translate it into its encoded form. These preserve special URI characters, such as `:` and `/`, instead of escaping them; it only escapes non-ASCII characters and characters that are invalid in URIs. Thus, they do essentially the same thing as typing in the address bar or putting a URI in an `<a href="...">` (though the behavior might vary somewhat between browser, and isn't exactly the same).

`encodeURIComponent` is intended for encoding only a single component of a URI, replacing special characters that are meaningful in URIs, so that you can use the component as a query parameter or path component in a longer URI.

Answer (score 0):

This one says it covers UTF-8. http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html. Might solve your problem