# stumbleupon badges and spanish characters

Tags: html, url, badge

using the stumbleupon badge code for a url like

```
http://www.test.com/¿cómo_se_dice
```

with the following snippet

```
<script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=2&r=http://www.test.com/¿cómo_se_dice"></script>
```

it will recognize the url as `http://www.test.com/cmo_se_dice` and remove the spanish characters.

is there a special way to treat the url before adding it to the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbleupon are actually doing it right.

This

```
http://www.test.com/¿cómo_se_dice
```

is  [not a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls).

You would need to either [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the URL before passing it through to the badge, or remove the special character.

Percent-encoding would result in this:

> http://www.test.com/%C2%BFc%C3%B3mo_se_dice

There's an online converter to play around with [here](http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp).