# how to use plus sign instead dashes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hey like i said in the question i want use the plus sign(+) instead of dashes so the posts will be like that:
some+post+test
another question , when i use non-latin characters the wordpress break the permalink and preserve just 30 words !! how can i solve that?

Comment: The `+` sign is a reserved character in URLs. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: hey Pekka , i know that plus sign is a reserved character , but there is million of sites use it ! there is no problem but i have a client who wants that , and what about the second problem , do you any idea dear?

Comment: why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @pekka because a client wants that's type of url ! i asked him to change it with '=' or underscores but he refuse .

Answer (score 0):

The + sign is a reserved character in URLs and will translate to a space .

From what you are saying, though, your underlying issue is that you want to use non-ASCII characters in URLs. That is not valid in the first place: You will have to percent encode the slug before inserting it. Most modern browsers will show the URL in its proper form anyway.

[Here](http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp) is an on-line tool for percent-encoding incoming data. For example, the UTF-8 input of

```
Crêpes
```

will translate to

```
 Cr%C3%AApes
```

Background info: [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: hey pikka like im said in the last comment for sure there is a method to use it ; there is many websites use plus sign for Spaces .

Comment: @Hamza you can try adding spaces to the WP slug and seeing whether they get converted to `+`. Other than that, I know of no easy way of changing Wordpress so it accepts that character. It's easy to do if you control your own web pages and URLs, but Wordpress is a more complex thing

Comment: yes that's true , that's why im posted the question because i have tried but i didn't get a result ; about the non-latin characters , wordpress cut the slug and preserve just 30 lettre !!

Comment: @Hamza well, try percent encoding. Although I can imagine that the 30 letter limit is something built into Wordpress.

Comment: @Pekka no its something related to octets , because if i entry an english title(with 1000000000000 words) all works fine !

Comment: @Hamza yes, as I said, you can't use non-ASCII characters in URLs. You need to percent encode them.

Comment: and how the visitor will see them in the browser?

Comment: @Hamza read by answer and the background info I link to. It's all there.

Comment: i read it but where i have to post the function into wordpress because im not friendly with it!

Comment: @Hamza you can percent escape the slug in the on-line tool to link to. If you want to do it automatically in WP: That I don't know. I would ask another question for that

Comment: for sure i'll not oblige the client to do that everytime per day! and thanks