# Non English Characters in URL ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, blogengine.net, non-english

I'm using Blogengine.Net as my blog engine. I'd like to provide SEO friendly addresses like:
http://www.mysite.com/post/پسسیبتجدید.aspx
But  blogengine changes the characters to not SEO friendly codes like:
http://www.mysite.com/post/d8aad8a7d9bedb8cdaa9-da86d987d8a7d8b1.aspx
My question is:

1. If you're familiar with Blogengine.net, do you know if this is related to ASP.Net or Blogengine.Net?
2. How can I prevent this behavior?

**UPDATE:** It *was* a BlogEngine.Net issue. version 2.0 supports non unicode characters in URL addresses.

Comment: I think its related to the `internet`

Comment: The strange thing is that I see many websites that just use non-english characters in their url addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The URL specs do not allow this** because they only allow a very limited set of characters.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4 for more information.

Comment: +1. Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Comment: True, and this is almost certainly why, but it's not generating the %s by the look of it just the hex - which Google won't understand.