# non english url aliases in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

i use url aliases in drupal.my path aliases string is not enlish (unicode). when i check link addresses in FF or Chrome they show correctly. but in IE i see addresses like this %D8%AA...
1)what can i  do to solve this problem?
2)How google indexes this url %D8%AA.... or NON ENGLISH (unicode strings)?

Comment: Here's some background on how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Comment: what about my second question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [transliteration module](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration), if you are creating the alias' through pathauto, otherwise you should use ASCII chars for the url alias' you create.

Nobody but google knows exactly how google does things. But I'm sure they will index any url. nomatter how it looks. Having an url with %xxx is not technically different from one without. You will, however, most likely loose any bonus that a semantic url can give you.

Comment: i dont use path auto. i use url aliases. what about my second question?