# php urldecode utf8 encoding question

Tags: php, encoding, url-encoding

when I'm trying to _GET url with urlencoded value (some cyrilic word):

http://example.com/?action=search&q=%E0%E2%F2%EE%EC%EE%E1%E8%EB%FC

after decoding:

```
echo urldecode($_GET['q']); // it prints: ���������
```

so, I need do conversion to utf-8 (because whole my application works with utf-8) via:

```
mb_convert_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8", "windows-1251");
```

and it helps, but **question**:

Who/what says it should be **EXACTLY** "windows-1251" ? where from it comes? 
if i'll use some other languages, how I can define appropriate encoding?
where is the magic?

(update): page encoding is utf-8
(update): actually, urldecode($_GET['q']) even not needed, looks like apache+php module doing everything, but, still can't understand where configs are

Comment: Where does the search query come from?

Comment: when typing in Firefox3 http://example.com/?action=search&q=автомобиль it converts automatically to: http://example.com/?action=search&q=%E0%E2%F2%EE%EC%EE%E1%E8%EB%FC

Comment: so its looks more like server side logic ... why urldecode converts string *EXACTLY* to windows-1251

Comment: @dmytriw because you are using windows-1251 on server side. Read our answers

Comment: @Pekka, no I dont, if you mean: 

    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

it doesn't help, plus <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> present as well 

so, its something different

Comment: Ah, I see. That's stange. Any chance of a live example?

Comment: @Pekka, what do you mean: "you are using windows-1251 on server side"? where :) ?

Comment: just check this out :) var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'])); // string(5) "UTF-8" var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8")); // string(5) "UTF-8" var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8, windows-1251")); // string(12) "Windows-1251" var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8, windows-1251, windows-1252")); // string(12) "Windows-1251"

Comment: @dmytri I think mb_detect_encoding() doesn't work properly here because it's URL encoded data. Not sure what is wrong here, the *input* seems to be windows-1251 (or similar) which is strange. I don't know

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you can't know that for sure, as it might change from request to request, especially if it is not always submitted from form, but sometimes send with ajax, or typed directly in address bar by user.

I work with an appliction which is Polish language. The application works with ISO-8859-2 codepage, and all the html output is served in this encoding.

The application receives request in two different encodings, depending on the context of request:

1. If the request is made as a result of form submit, then the encoding is the same as the html page with the submitted form. I think it could be altered with accept-charset attribute of form element, but I have not tried it.
2. If the request is made with Ajax then it is always UTF-8 (at least in Chrome and Firefox, as our client uses only those browsers).
3. If the request is manually entered into the URL, then it is usually UTF-8, but if it was a bookmark or something like that, then it might be other encoding (depends on how the bookmark was created).

So, really no way to know for sure. If you can, always use UTF-8. Otherwise use charset detection (check if it is UTF-8, if not fall back to the most probable encoding based on the language your application is using).

I use the following code:

```
<?php
$t = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń';
echo mb_detect_encoding($t, 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-2');
```

Best regards, 
SWilk

Comment: just check this out :) 



    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'])); // string(5) "UTF-8"

    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8")); // string(5) "UTF-8"

    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8, windows-1251")); // string(12) "Windows-1251"

    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($_GET['q'], "UTF-8, windows-1251, windows-1252")); // string(12) "Windows-1251"

Answer (score 1):

it is not apache nor mod_php issue. PHP does decode urlencoding automatically but it doesn't encode anything, so, there is nothing to worry about

as it seems from this

> when typing in Firefox3 example.com/?action=search&q=автомобиль it converts automatically to: example.com/?action=search&q=%E0%E2%F2%EE%EC%EE%E1%E8%EB%FC

it's more like browser or operation system issue.

it seems that your OS encoding is single-byte and browser does urlencode your single-byte string.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep UTF8 and set your page's charset to UTF8 using the appropriate content-type header:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type non-ASCII characters directly into the URL search bar, the browser seems to automatically convert the characters into UTF-8 and URL encoded entities. I have no hard data on this but the behaviour makes sense. Related question here: [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Your page is using `windows-1252` or some other single-byte character set as its output encoding, which is why you need to convert the character data first.

You could change your page's output encoding to UTF-8 to save yourself that step, but that may have other consequences (like the need to use multi-byte string functions and/or a different encoding for database output, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

windows-1251 is an 8-bit character encoding designed to cover languages that use Cyrillic alphabets.
[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)

You might have set the charset to windows-1251 in your webpage

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. I use `adobe dreameweaver cs4` (non english version)

I solve it as below:

1. add `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of the PHP page file.
2. **IMPORTANT**  In `adobe dreameweaver`, you should modify `Page Properties` from the `top menu`  `Modify (M) -> Page Properties (P)`, choose `Title/coding` and modify `unicode` to `unicode (uft-8)` handly.

(sorry, these menu words are translated to english, maybe not the real words)