# Format URL in Arabic Language instead of English Language

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i have link with this format :

```
http://site.com/news/view/1.html
```

i want change it to :

```
http://site.com/خبر/عنوان-الخبر
```

which خبر is equal "news"

and "عنوان-الخبر" equal title of news page

i want do it by .htaccess and at the same time i want save old urls by redirect it by 301

and i want know if i need to do any edits in php files for news ?

Regardes ,

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

This depends how your logic scripts are currently set up to handle your URL's. If you're using a preg_match or some other way to get the data from the URL other than $_GET you'll have to change those variables to $_GET as you will be passing that information via the .htaccess RewriteRule.