# Browser Support Unicode URL

Tags: url, unicode, dns

What is the browser support for having images, links, scripts... containing unicode characters in the domain name?

For example does IE5+, chrome, firefox, opera, safari, and  mobile browsers (Dolfin, Blackberry Webkit, MicroB, Phantom, IEMobile...) all support the following statement?

```
<script src=☺.com/s.js></script>
```

Just attempting to understand the portability of the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia's *Internationalized domain name* article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) says this:

> Mozilla 1.4, Netscape 7.1, Opera 7.11 were among the first
>   applications to support IDNA. A browser plugin is available for
>   Internet Explorer 6 to provide IDN support. Internet Explorer
>   7.0[13][14] and Windows Vista's URL APIs provide native support for IDN.[15]

Considering the age of those browsers, I'd guess that any newer browser, including any WebKit-based browser, supports IDNs.