# UTF8 Char in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8

i have a problem. I hope you can help me. I don’t speak english very well, but i try to explain me good as i can.

I am from argentina, so, i have to work with the “ñ” character. For SEO, i want include the “ñ” at the url for some words, so, for example, i have:

- Controller: webdesign.php
- Route: $route[‘diseñoweb’] = “webdesign”;

But, when i enter to “www.domain.com/diseñoweb” it doesn’t work. And i need the “ñ” character in the url.
Do somebody know how can i do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to allow that char in your config, for example you can have something like these…

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9_\-ñ';
```

Then, at system/core/URI.php, on line 231, replace

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
```

to

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", utf8_encode($str)))
```

Comment: Can i do that without hack the core files?

Comment: Well, you can extends the URI class, and replace/overide related function of that block. But bear in mind, that CI is really strict in their URI. As default, CI doesnt permit any "unusual" char as security reason. So if you really need to do this, the option is to modify above section.

Comment: CI probably prohibits the characters because non-ASCII characters won't work directly - see here for background [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)

Comment: i combine both Pekka and toopay solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is most likely not going to work as you want, because URLs can't contain non-ASCII characters. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls) for background.

I think you need to create a route for the URLencoded version, like so:

```
$route['dise%c3%b1oweb'] = "webdesign";
```

if you then enter a URL containing

```
diseñoweb
```

a modern browser will automatically URLencode the character.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
$route[rawurlencode('diseñoweb')] = “webdesign”;
```