# Special chars in querystrings in IE don't get properly decoded

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, character-encoding

I have an issue with IE, when sending a querystring with special characters in it as for instance with the "Ø" (name=bjørn) in asp.net will be somehow encoded into "name=bj%ufffdrn", "ø" gets translated into "%ufff"

I would like to know, how to decode this into the right charaters.

This only happens with IE not with FF, Ch or opera.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably the correct behaviour. Where are you sending the query string from? Can you show some code?

Comment: Background: [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)

Comment: The code is generated in wordpress using php and "htmlspecialchars()" function and then will generate a link that will connect to an asp.net handler where i'm getting this problem decoding the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using htmlspecialchars to encode a URL.  In PHP use `urlencode` (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).  Then ASP.NET should decode the URL parameters for you.