# Encoding of $_SERVER variables like $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I need to do some string operations on `$_SERVER` value especially `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

How PHP encodes such strings? Should I use `mb_*` family functions?

To understand better my question, let's say I have a page on my webserver called like this:

```
ããã.php
```

And I need to get the second char:

```
echo mb_substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1,1);
```

Comment: What string operations? Encodes when? Use for what?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: especially string operation like: `substr`

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I have added an example

Comment: Could you show a real life example of what you're trying to achieve, including a real life URL? That might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How PHP encodes such strings?

PHP won't do anything to the string, but the web browser will usually [percent encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) any non-ASCII characters in `REQUEST_URI`. (I say "usually" because I have seen IE *not* do it. I expect, however, Apache to do the job in that case - but I'm not entirely sure whether it will. You'd have to try out.)

Running [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/urldecode) will decode those characters.

Related reading:  [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` usually doesn't contain stuff which would require usage of Multibyte functions so I guess if you don't tend to do unusual stuff with the request URIs such as stuffing them with non-ASCII characters (caused by weird URI rewrites etc.) you are safe to use the "normal" PHP string manipulation functions.

Comment: @yes `ããã.html` is not a valid URL - the special characters will be percent encoded. see [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)