# Codeigniter unicode URI read as %E6

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode, uri

For example I put domain.com/controller/木村文乃 on my URI.

CodeIgniter read it as %E6%9C%A8%E6%9D%91%E6%96%87%E4%B9%83 when I output the 木村文乃.

```
function($page)
{
 echo $page;
}
```

it outputs as %E6%9C%A8%E6%9D%91%E6%96%87%E4%B9%83

This problem happens since I move server from centOS to debian.

What could be the problem?

I have checked php.ini settings, etc.

Comment: That looks pretty much like it should be. [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have it, this should display propper name.

```
function($page) {
    $page=urldecode($page);
    echo $page;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because *special characters* are not allowed in URLs whether you use CodeIgniter or any other framework, it is standard.

The reason why you see these percent characters converted is because CI converts special characters using `urlencode` so that browser can understand them and that works for you behind the scenes.