# urldecode wordpress menus

Tags: wordpress, friendly-url, urldecode

Im using word press menus to show menus on my UTF-8 Hebrew site.
For some reason word-press doesn't automatically implement URL decode to the links so my links are pretty ugly.

%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%91

how can i solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue since unicode characters are not allowed in 
URI.

[Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

EDIT :
If you really want to urldecode your links, you should modify your theme : instead of using `wp_nav_menu`, you can easily build your menu using [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) and do what you want with urls.

Comment: thats not totally correct , the browsers are reading the utf url and decode it , i cant write in hebrew here but you can check this url and you will see you go to a legitimate page. the only problem is - it is ugly ! , that is the reason i need to urldecode it .... 
http://www.muchmarketing.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%98.html

Comment: It is ugly only when you copy/paste the url. Well, answer updated.