# Why Internet Explorer doesn't url-encode the urls?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, url

I launch the IE (7th version) as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://somewhere.com/q=фыва"
```

except that "фыва" part is replaced by "????" in `cmd`.

When IE boots up, it displays the expected url in address bar, but if I take a look at the actual traffic, `????` is sent (`3f3f3f3f`). I expected it to url-encode it (and actually, it *does* url-encode spaces to "%20").

Is there a way to make it send the proper data to server?

Comment: From cmd try running `chcp 65001` first to switch to a unicode code page (you will need a unicode font (lucida) to see it accurately)

Comment: This is not a problem with `IE` but with `cmd` and the encoding of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode characters are forbidden in urls see

[Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

% encode the unicode chars **yourself** to - http://somewhere.com/q=%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0

its probably removing them as a *feature*