# loading image in "Internet Explorer" - parameter to the server is "????"

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

problem loading image in Internet Explorer (10) while at chrome & firefox it's ok 
when the **username** parameter is in hebrew (rtl language)
the problem occurs for css and html:

```
background: 0 url('php/ajax/ajax-user-image-read.php?username=רועי') no-repeat';

img src="php/ajax/ajax-user-image-read.php?username=רועי" alt=""
```

both works ok for english

```
background: 0 url('php/ajax/ajax-user-image-read.php?username=roee') no-repeat';

img src="php/ajax/ajax-user-image-read.php?username=roee" alt=""
```

when hebrew I receive the username parameter as ???? at the server side.

my html page has `meta charset="UTF-8"` and all other hebrew works ok.

I don't think the php code will help here because it receives question marks and not valid data but here it is:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '../gw-database.php';
require_once '../gw-functions/gw-functions-user.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        if (!empty($_GET['username'])) {

            $username = ('current' === $_GET['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : $_GET['username'] ;

            $image = userImageGet($username);
            if (false !== $image) {

                header('Content-Type: '.$image['type']);
                echo $image['image'];
            }
            else {
                logRunTimeMessage($_SESSION['username'], 'server', $error, 'In file '.strrchr(__FILE__, "\\").' at line '.__LINE__.' - Error fail to get user image', time());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you receiving the username, using what code? Please show the relevant portions of the PHP code where you are using the user name

Comment: You need to urlencode the Hebrew (the other browsers do that for you). Take a look at this list of [allowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) URL characters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't believe that is true, and I don't think that Wikipedia article is correct.  I believe you can use UTF-8 characters as-is in the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Internet Explorer doesn't url-encode the urls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492727/why-internet-explorer-doesnt-url-encode-the-urls)

Comment: @Brad Do [you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13492806/2970947)? You can use UTF-8 in the hostname, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [URLENCODE](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

**Example:**

```
$username = 'רוע';
/*... some code ...*/
src="php/ajax/ajax-user-image-read.php?username=<?php echo urlencode($username);?>" alt=""
```