# twitter intent share japanese text not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter, twitter-share

I have a simple share button by which twitter share url & text

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=ドキドキしたい15才】 さんにおすすめのマンガは 「トレース 科捜研法医研究員の追想」 あなたも診断してみる？ ⇒ &hashtags=hello&url=encodeURIComponent('https://google.com')
```

This is working in every browser but when IE11 its not working. Showing 400 bad request. Can anybody help me.

[image]

Sometimes not show 400 bad request but japanese text showing as question mark

***When I open this URL into chrome then it works, after that if I copy this URL from Chrome then also work in IE but direct URL not works. Perhaps URL encoding issue. please help***

Comment: Personally I not a 400 error in my IE.
Check your cache, cookie, etc... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xnd.png) On the other hand, I do have"????" instead of characters, the problem comes from encoding.
I'm not sure what programming you uses, but in PHP there's this: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally The issue fixed. I have encoded text also like URL and its working in IE11 also. So I use `encodeURIComponent('Japanese text')` like below & then working

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=encodeURIComponent('ドキドキしたい15才】 さんにおすすめのマンガは 「トレース 科捜研法医研究員の追想」 あなたも診断してみる？ ⇒')&hashtags=hello&url=encodeURIComponent('https://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to %-Encode your URL to UTF8. IE 11 does not do this.
Here's a relevant SO question:
 [Why Internet Explorer doesn't url-encode the urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492727/why-internet-explorer-doesnt-url-encode-the-urls)