# Can I use the invisible characters in an URL?

Tags: url, special-characters, url-encoding

I recently discovered that ALT+255, also known as the invisible character, seemed to be usable in a website URL.
Depending on the browser, it either shows up encoded as %C2, or looks like a space. 
Chrome and IE seemed to display it unencoded.
It is *really* weird to see (something that looks like) spaces in URL's, but at the same time it is very human-readable.

However, my gut feeling tells me using this is a very bad idea. Is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non latin symbols in url, php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540092/non-latin-symbols-in-url-php)

Comment: As far as I'm able to deduce with a Windows system at hand, Alt+255 is a non-breaking space. That can be put into the URL the same way any arbitrary byte can be put into the URL: by percent encoding it. For why it displays or doesn't display, see the aforelinked duplicate.