# Browser Support for UTF8 Encoded Characters in URL's

Tags: url, browser, encoding, utf-8, url-encoding

If I navigate to the following URL with a special UTF8 encoded character I get different results in web browsers:

> [http://example.com/lörickè](http://example.com/l%C3%B6rick%C3%A8)

- Firefox 37 - Shows the correct URL as above.
- Chrome 42 - Shows the correct URL as above.
- Edge - Shows the correct URL as above.
- IE 11 - Shows percent encoded URL http://example.com/l%c3%b6rick%c3%a8/

Where can I find a list of browsers and versions that support this feature and are there any announcements of whether the new Microsoft Edge browser supports this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247525/internet-explorer-does-not-display-chinese-characters-from-the-url/19542940#19542940) StackOverflow post highlights the above issue for those interested.

Answer (score 15):

What is shown in browser address bars is not necessarily what is used internally.

If you enter `http://example.com/lörickè` in Firefox, it gets shown like that, but it actually gets percent-encoded and becomes `http://example.com/l%C3%B6rick%C3%A8`. This is for usability reasons (or, if IRIs are not supported, like in HTTP/1.1, for transforming an IRI into a URI), so users don’t necessarily have to enter the correct URL (with percent-encoding), and don’t get confused by seeing these cryptic parts.

You can easily check what really gets used by [copy-pasting the URL from the address bar into a text document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611595/1591669).

So the three browsers from your example probably use the same URI (i.e., percent-encoded), but two browsers decided to display the un-encoded variant instead.

Comment: This is exactly what happens.  What is *displayed* to the user is not guaranteed to be what is actually *transmitted* to the server, or used for *internal tracking* (cache, favorites, history, etc).

Comment: Is there a way to guess based on the user-agent string whether a browser supports this or not? To potentially serve them URLs with fully accented characters, but not to browsers that would show percentages.