# Put title alias for URL safe

Tags: php, regex

I try that URL safe with following function, but it don't work for Arabic language. How can fixed it?

**[DEMO Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/A967aR)**

```
<?php
    function stringURLSafe($string)
{
    // remove any '-' from the string since they will be used as concatenaters
    $str = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);


    // Trim white spaces at beginning and end of alias and make lowercase
    $str = trim(strtolower($str));

    // Remove any duplicate whitespace, and ensure all characters are alphanumeric
    $str = preg_replace('/(\s|[^A-Za-z0-9\-])+/', '-', $str);

    // Trim dashes at beginning and end of alias
    $str = trim($str, '-');

    return $str;
}
echo stringURLSafe('موقع إخباري: مرتبط بقناة {العربية} يقدم (على) مدار');
```

I want in output as:

> ```
> موقع-إخباري-مرتبط-بقناة-العربية-يقدم-على-مدار
> ```

Comment: That's not a valid URL, though. You'd have to `urlencode()` the string. [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regexp to this one: 
`$str = preg_replace('/(\s|[^\p{Arabic}\w0-9\-])+/u', '-', $str);`
Here result:
موقع-إخباري-مرتبط-بقناة-العربية-يقدم-على-مدار