# How to open url having Arabic text using php file-get-contents function

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want  to get html from a URL having some Arabic like

```
http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html
```

using php.
I tried with

```
file_get_html("http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html")
```

but it is giving the following error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in filename.php
```

Please help.

```
http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html
```

is for reference only, doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, there you have it. A 404 means it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URLs [can't contain non-ASCII characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Where it seems that they do, it's in fact the browser silently converting your characters into URLescaped ones in the background.

When you paste this URL into your browser:

```
http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html
```

will in reality look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1.html
```

PHP doesn't have this ability to silently convert characters; you'll have to do it manually. To do that,
run PHP's `urlencode()` over the URL before making the call.

Comment: Thanks,I tried to open URL using urlencode() but its still giving error `[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in filename.php`

Comment: Can you edit the full code of your request into your question, including the `urlencode()` call?

Comment: `$url = "http://www.example.com/2013/07/31/الاختبار.html"; $url = urlencode($url); $html1 = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: @Mobi you need to limit the `urlencode`  to the Arabic script, otherwise the `://` will get encoded as well