# Error 400 when open tag in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, genesis

When i open tags in Arabic like :-

```
http://www.domain.com/tag/تقنية
```

Its open for me error 400

but its work with English tag like :-

```
http://www.domain.com/tag/tech
```

where the error

I am use `Genesis Framework`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963784/how-to-open-url-having-arabic-text-using-php-file-get-contents-function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls
```

Above will help you to convert your arabic URL to browser friendly..

Comment: not all tags not open, some tag open and some not open , this tag open with me `http://www.domain.com/tag/لعب`

Comment: @AbuKotsh - Cheers :)