# php Korean URL Slug

Tags: php, string, url, character-encoding, slug

I do url slugging by replacing(similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/sgmurphy/3098978)). My problem is that in Korean language connected words make problem for me:

```
// Korean
'ㄱ'=>'k','ㅋ'=>'kh','ㄲ'=>'kk','ㄷ'=>'t','ㅌ'=>'th','ㄸ'=>'tt','ㅂ'=>'p',
'ㅍ'=>'ph','ㅃ'=>'pp','ㅈ'=>'c','ㅊ'=>'ch','ㅉ'=>'cc','ㅅ'=>'s','ㅆ'=>'ss',
'ㅎ'=>'h','ㅇ'=>'ng','ㄴ'=>'n','ㄹ'=>'l','ㅁ'=>'m', 'ㅏ'=>'a','ㅓ'=>'e','ㅗ'=>'o',
'ㅜ'=>'wu','ㅡ'=>'u','ㅣ'=>'i','ㅐ'=>'ay','ㅔ'=>'ey','ㅚ'=>'oy','ㅘ'=>'wa','ㅝ'=>'we',
'ㅟ'=>'wi','ㅙ'=>'way','ㅞ'=>'wey','ㅢ'=>'uy','ㅑ'=>'ya','ㅕ'=>'ye','ㅛ'=>'oy',
'ㅠ'=>'yu','ㅒ'=>'yay','ㅖ'=>'yey',
```

the problem is that korean characters combine and make new characters: 및
which is made of three characters. so how to slug korean urls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: i want to have clear url(slugged) not percented

Comment: it's not permitted as per the RFC mentioned in the answer I linked to.

Comment: check if http://php.net/iconv can help (with the //TRANSLIT parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to extract the three characters building up the one. So  `('ㅁ', 'ㅣ', 'ㅊ')` extracted from `및`

I found some useful links (assuming unicode), however I didn't test any of the codes listed below:

- [PHP Version (simple explanation)](http://me2.do/5u0rl3qP)
- [Java version](http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=imisehi&logNo=150076475503&categoryNo=4&viewDate=&currentPage=1&listtype=0)
- [PHP version](http://www.phpschool.com/gnuboard4/bbs/board.php?bo_table=tipntech&wr_id=51435)

If you manage to extract the three characters, I think the remaining part is simple. Here is [a Google link](https://www.google.co.kr/search?hl=ko&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=PHP+%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80+%EC%9E%90%EC%86%8C+%EB%B6%84%EB%A6%AC&gbv=2&oq=PHP+%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80+%EC%9E%90%EC%86%8C+%EB%B6%84%EB%A6%AC&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3...907.5650.0.6111.35.28.5.0.0.6.159.2699.13j15.28.0....0...1c.1j4.24.heirloom-hp..14.21.1576.msmCFbtYHpc) to start searching by yourself.