# PHP $_GET query string in chinese

Tags: php, url, browser, url-rewriting

I am passing query string like `http://hk.sitedomain.com/restaurant/南小館-The-Dining-Room/`

and when I try to use $_GET function

its converting sometime like

`%E5%8D%97%E5%B0%8F%E9%A4%A8 The Dining Room`

I would like to get the exact chinese url in $_GET function.

Is it possible to use Chinese in browser URL or do browsers support only English urls?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the browser. My chrome successfully displayed it in its original form. And - yes, everything that is not ascii (and not only that) must be encoded.

Comment: `$_GET` is not  a function, nor relevant. That's entirely browser/configuration-dependent. See also [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)