# Mysql LIKE show unknown characters

Tags: php, mysql, get, sql-like

I tried to filter some data from a mysql table.

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
$name = "cable";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM stock WHERE item LIKE '%$name%'";
?>
<a target="_blank" href="test2.php?link=<?php echo $sql; ?>" >click</a>
```

I tried to get the sql statement using the $_GET[link] from the next page. (test2.php). Here's the code from TEST2.PHP

```
<?php    
include ("connection.php");   
$link = $_GET['link'];
echo $link;
```

then the echo $link show me a different value. It doesn't display "cable". Instead, it displays

```
SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item LIKE 'Êble%'
```

can you tell me why CABLE became Êble ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ayyanar said, yes, its not an good idea to pass a `SQL query` in `URL`.

But if you still want to achieve that you can do something like this:

TEST1.PHP

```
<?php
$name = "cable";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM stock WHERE item LIKE '%--$name--%'";
?>
<a target="_blank" href="test2.php?link=<?php echo $sql; ?>" >click</a>
```

TEST2.PHP

```
<?php
$link = $_GET['link'];    
$link = str_replace(
  array('%--', '--%'), 
  array('%', '%'), 
  $link
);
echo $link;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea to pass SQL statement in URL. please refer below link for reference,
[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

If you want to pass special charaters through URL,you can use,

```
urlencode($url);
```