# System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode method gives wrong result with different language value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode method in  my project. When I am encoding name in English language then I got correct result. For example,

```
string temp = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Jewelry");
```

then I got exact result in temp variable. But if I wrote name in Russian language then I got different result.

```
string temp = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ювелирные изделия");
```

then I got value in temp variable like "%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5+%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f"

Can anyone help me how to achieve exact name as per language?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method has "done the right thing" for you!

It encodes non-ASCII characters so that it can be valid in all of the cases and transmit over the Internet. If you put your `temp` variable in an URL as a parameter, you will get your correct result at server side. That's what UrlEncode means for. Here your question is not a problem at all.
So please have a look at this link for further reading to understand about URL Encoding: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

If you input that Russian word to the "URL Encoding Functions" part in the page I have given, it will return the same result as `Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method does.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me how to achieve exact name as per language?

In short: not with that method, but it might depend on what is your exact goal.

In details:

In general URIs as defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986/) (see [Section 2: Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)) may contain any of the following characters: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`. Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh).

This is why [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) produces

```
UrlEncode("Jewelry") -> "Jewelry"
UrlEncode("ювелирные изделия") -> "%d1%8e%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5+%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f"
```

The string of `"ювелирные изделия"` contains characters that are not allowed in a URL as per RFC 3986.

Today, [modern browsers could work with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls) in URL it might be not necessary to use UrlEncode(). See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ybgt96ms/