# Make url in different language meteor?

Tags: url, meteor, routes, iron-router

I am working with tutorial. In which got concept of router. My question is
can we make route in different language like in Russian 
`http://localhost:3000/свяжитесь с нами`i  or in persian like 
`http://localhost:3000/تماس با ما` . I want to make url in other language rather than english. can any one help me  to make url in different language in meteor.

Comment: This is not a Meteor-specific question. Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `encodeURIComponent()` function of javascript. which solved my problem.