# What is this reddot character  doing in the URL (FireFox only)?

Tags: html, url, firefox, character-encoding

I happened to stumble upon a website and the URL had a red blob in it. Seriously, I've never seen something like this. What's up with that?!

http://blacklistdeclassified.net/2015/10/30/%F0%9F%94%B4-script-35-arioch-cain/

NB One needs to actually navigate to the page to get to see it. The below is a screenshot on my system (WinX, FF). The red thing isn't PhotoShopped. It's actually red!

[image]

Comment: It's dependent on fonts and rendering engines. On windows 7 and arch linux they render in black and white.

Comment: @the8472 So you're saying that you're not seeing the same thing in the title as I just pasted a screenshot? (Of course the screenshot has the color but I'm referring to the actual text at the top.) That's dreadful. It means that the colors and appearance are vastly platform-dependent. Not okay...

Comment: win7: http://i.imgur.com/gODh25T.png arch: http://i.imgur.com/8s7bltK.png I bet it also looks different on mobile systems.

Comment: I can vote for migration, and have done so, but it requires a consensus vote from multiple users. A mod can do it immediately if the OP requests a migration and the grounds are reasonable. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a unicode character,  , also known as the "Large Red Circle". UTF-8 F0 9F 94 B4. See [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f534/index.htm) for more representations and information. It seems from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852/544198) that it isn't actually part of the URL, but rather that Firefox, and possibly other browsers, decode it, mostly for use of non-English languages that require the use of Unicode. There is some work going on to support Unicode in more locations, but it hasn't been completely accomplished.

Comment: But... But... I'm turning 40 next week, been doing computer stuff for 25-30. And I've never, ever, ever seen that! Special weird characters - yes. But this one is actually of **different color**! How does that render?! What if we print it out? Or show it on a monochromatic screen... Is it only me what finds it weird? What the duck?! (Typo intended.) What's the purpose? Are there others?

Comment: It's fairly new that it's allowed, but yes, it's pretty cool. I strongly suspect there are other unicode characters that would work the same.

Comment: I'm both amazed and unhappy. The former because it's pretty cool and hacky. The latter because nobody's told me... Also unhappy because now, I can imagine every other website will try to stick out by putting those stuff in the URL to be hit on google. I mean, I'm pretty sane person and I'm already planning to update my domain name...

Comment: A lot of the recent additions to Unicode will be rendered in color on most platforms, and slightly differently on each. Apart from the color, nothing new here. See e.g. http://www.unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html#2.3

Comment: Example renderings from multiple different platforms: http://emojipedia.org/pig-face/ (Twitter is clearly superior!)

Comment: @tripleee Well, I guess I was in need to be educated, hehe. But when you said *nothing new here*, I felt in my head *...so, we landed on Mars!* followed by *...apart from different planet, nothing new here...*. Perhaps I'm easily amazed but I was a bit chocked when I saw the reddy dotty thingy, hahaha.

Comment: I mean platform (and font) differences in rendering a glyph are completely unsurprising even if you are unaware of Unicode.

Comment: @tripleee I see where you come from and in the general case I agree. Here, it appeared as such a huge difference so I question if the rendering to such different looks is thought through. The name of the glyph is *big **red** dot*. Seems as the rendering is... not colorful... enough for some platforms. But in technical terms, I totally see your point.