# Disable URL encoding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, iis, encode

Hello I'm not trying to use space or anything like that. all my urls are standard with dash separated words but the characters are in persian so instead of

`/%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C`

I wanna see

`/آرایشی`

The links are already saved as the second one but when it shows it on webpage it automatically encodes it.
My CMS can handle getting requests like the second one and auto redirect. I've tried changing config file and some globalization settings but no luck yet.

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852/107625) helps a bit?

Comment: @UweKeim Well it describes it but no solution :( thx tho

Comment: Is the url is stored in the database?

Comment: @AliSoltani Yes it is.