# Check if file with korean character exists on server with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to check if a pdf file exists on my server or not.

PDF files are named in korean like abc.com/토보토보.pdf

I have tried :

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    console.log(http.status);
}
```

But the problem is it always encoded to *example.com/%C3%AD%C2%86%C2%A0%C3%AB%C2%B3%C2%B4%C3%AD%C2%86%C2%A0%C3%AB%C2%B3%C2%B4.pdf*

```
UrlExists("example.com/토보토보.pdf")
01:51:29.144 VM428:14 
HEAD
http://example.com/%ED%86%A0%EB%B3%B4%ED%86%A0%EB%B3%B4.pdf     
404     (Not Found)
```

How do i get the solution to my problem?

Comment: unescape is deprecated since JavaScript 1.5

Comment: What backend language are you using?  It might be more appropriate to ask how to make the backend decode the hex encoding

Comment: The URL encoding is normal. You will get that with most characters that aren't alphanumeric. Even spaces get encoded into `%20`. Pretty much anything should be able to understand what a URL encoded string should be decoded as and give you the correct resource.

Comment: I have reframed my problem to be more clear.

Comment: I updated my answer and stuff, try using JSON to encode the chars

Comment: Your server will need to parse the JSON and look up the file

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want to run the base filename part of your url through `encodeURIComponent` before sending the http request out.

This should convert your korean text to the escaped text (with the percentage signs) and then it can find it.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: I just tried it, Didn't work. It is matching the encoded file name and getting 404 error.

Comment: I'm sure you're sure the file is there. Can you copy and paste the response you get?

Answer (score 0):

try `window.encodeURI` or `window.encodeURIComponent`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

```
// encodes characters such as ?,=,/,&,:
console.log(encodeURIComponent('?x=шеллы'));
// expected output: "%3Fx%3D%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"

console.log(encodeURIComponent('?x=test'));
// expected output: "%3Fx%3Dtest"
```

or try this:

```
const pdf = {name:"토보토보"};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify(pdf),
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
})
.then(function(res){
  return res.json()
})
.then(function(v){
  // read the result
})
```

or you could do a GET request by putting JSON as a query param:

```
const pdf = {name:"토보토보"};
const url = "example.com?pdf=${JSON.stringify(pdf)}"
fetch(url).then(...);
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, 

My file name on the server is  토보토보.pdf , If i use encodeURIComponent on the file name it gives encoded characters which do not match the filename on the server and hence return 404 code.

Comment: yeah idk, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Comment: one thing your server could do is receive a JSON request, instead of a plain url, and then look up the PDF to see if it exists

Comment: Using JSON to encode the info is probably a good bet here. Your server has to receive and parse the JSON and then look up the pdf by name.