# what is the uni code encoding error in the code below

Tags: python, xhtml2pdf

### I'm getting the following unicode encoding error .

When I'm running the program presented below, I'm getting a unicode encoding-related error

```py
import bs4
import requests
from xhtml2pdf import pisa  # import python module
from xhtml2pdf.config.httpconfig import httpConfig

res = requests.get("https://www.insightsonindia.com/2018/06/04/insights-daily-current-affairs-04-june-2018/")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
pf = soup.find("div", class_="pf-content")

sourceHtml =str(pf)
outputFilename = "test.pdf"

def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
    # open output file for writing (truncated binary)

    httpConfig.save_keys('nosslcheck', True)

    resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")

    # convert HTML to PDF
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml, dest=resultFile, encoding="utf-8")

    # close output file
    resultFile.close()  # close output file

    # return True on success and False on errors
    return pisaStatus.err

# Main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pisa.showLogging()
    convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
```

The error is given below

```
self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm trying to download a portion of a website using xhtml2pdf. To do that I used bs4 and scrape the site and store it. Then save it into pdf by using xhtml2pdf.
Most of the time it worked like charm. But for this instance it is giving me error. Link to the full code in github is given below

Link to full code is available [here](https://github.com/ksananthu/pdf_download/blob/master/test3.py)

xhtml2pdf is encoding with ascii, Since my html file contain non ascii characters it is showing error. And I don't know how to change the encoder in xhtml2pdf. Omitting non-ascii character is not not an option. If I ignore it then link to the image will be corrupted and image will not show in pdf.

complete traceback

````
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 80, in 
    convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
  File "test3.py", line 68, in convertHtmlToPdf
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml, dest=resultFile, encoding= 'utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 97, in pisaDocument
    encoding, context=context, xml_output=xml_output)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 59, in pisaStory
    pisaParser(src, context, default_css, xhtml, encoding, xml_output)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 759, in pisaParser
    pisaLoop(document, context)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 700, in pisaLoop
    pisaLoop(node, context, path, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 644, in pisaLoop
    pisaLoop(nnode, context, path, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 644, in pisaLoop
    pisaLoop(nnode, context, path, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 644, in pisaLoop
    pisaLoop(nnode, context, path, **kw)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 514, in pisaLoop
    attr = pisaGetAttributes(context, node.tagName, node.attributes)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 124, in pisaGetAttributes
    nv = c.getFile(nv)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 818, in getFile
    return getFile(name, relative or self.pathDirectory)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\util.py", line 738, in getFile
    file = pisaFileObject(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\util.py", line 644, in init
    conn.request("GET", path)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1240, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Users\Ananthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1107, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
````

Comment: There is no ASCII equivalent for U+2019 (’); the `encode` method doesn't try to match non-ASCII characters with a similar ASCII character.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure why `CreatePDF` (the only likely candidate) is trying to convert arbitrary Unicode text to ASCII.

Comment: @caco3 please refer full code given below the link.

Comment: @chepner How can I make this program work, Do you have any suggestion ? Please refer full code below. I'm a novice in python. So please explain the process also

Comment: Don't post a link to your full code. Post *here* a complete, minimal example that we could run to reproduce the error.

Comment: @chepner Complete code is posted

Comment: What version of python are you using to run your program?

Comment: @snakecharmerb python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the retrieved html contains `img` tags some of whose `src` attributes are urls which contain the `'\u2019'` ('RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK') character.

xhtml2pdf is passing these urls to python's [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) module without escaping them first. http.client tries to encode the urls as ASCII before retrieving them, and the error happens.

This can be worked around by escaping the urls in the retrieved html before generating the pdf.

[urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) provides the tools to do this.

```
from urllib import parse
...
res = requests.get("https://www.insightsonindia.com/2018/06/04/insights-daily-current-affairs-04-june-2018/")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
pf = soup.find("div", class_="pf-content")

imgs = pf.find_all('img')
for img in imgs: 
    url = img['src'] 
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = parse.urlparse(url)
    new_path = parse.quote(path)
    new_url = parse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, new_path, params, query, fragment))
    img['src'] = new_url

sourceHtml =str(pf)
outputFilename = "test.pdf"
...
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852/5320906) provide some background information on unicode and urls.

Comment: Thank you. It's worked like a charm