# Is it safe to use emojis and asterisks * in URLs?

Tags: url, emoji

Are these valid URLs to use in a web app?

```
https://example.com/take-a-

https://example.com/calc/2*2
```

Will there be any unexpected behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: The other half of this question has been asked and answered on Webmasters: [Can I use asterisks in URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/can-i-use-asterisks-in-urls)