# Next.js throw 404 error for a file which includes unicode file name(non ascii)

Tags: next.js

http://localhost:3000/a/%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80.txt

the file located under public directory (static).
alphabet file name is okay but unicode (non ascii) file name or path always occurs 404 error
no matter there is a file in the folder.
what's wrong with this??

Comment: Possible duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: No it doesn't. No. Url is already encoded by urlencode as I showed in the question (the url shown). but somehow next.js can't serve the file properly. I don't know why.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you find a solution, @Lucas1027?