# Rewrite URL convert to Lation charcter asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, sitemap

hey guys in first place i would be thankful for  all of you
im using asp.net im trying to rewrite my URL but i have an issue that when I'm trying to share my link or write it in my XML sitemap file  it's become that's way

```
   https://www.me-future.com/Articl/3157/%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B0%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%81%D9%83-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%83-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-
```

but my URL should be that's way

```
   https://www.me-future.com/Articl/3157/احذر-من-استخدام-هاتفك-المحمول-في-تلك-الحالات
```

thx a lot for your help guys and thx for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: for sorry no the problem is when i try to share my link it's at social networks it's turn into Latino charter it's work and my follower can enter the link  but it's looking bad plus the sitemap URL it's Latino character too im using asp.net any way thx a lot for you help I'm really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get the original url before sharing it to the others like this :
    var originalUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode("https://www.me-future.com/Articl/3157/%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B0%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%81%D9%83-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%83-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-");
```

Comment: var originalUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode("https://www.me-future.com/Articl/" + lblRoutid.Text);

Comment: it's still not working when im trying to share or write in my xml file

Comment: @DarwieshMustafa what's the exact value in  "lblRoutid.Text"

Comment: thx for replying me the lblRoutid.Text = Page.RouteData.Values["name"] as string;

Comment: @DarwieshMustafa i think you have to cross check this concatenation  "me-future.com/Articl" + lblRoutid.Text". i.e the exact value of Page.RouteData.Values["name"] .