# Japanese Characters in shell(zsh) does not work in url

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

## What I want

- I want to do Google Search from Mac terminal(zsh).
- The search query includes Japanese Character.

## Error

In Mac terminal (zsh), I run this script:

```
username@usernamenoAir ~ % open -a "Google Chrome" "https://google.co.jp/search?q=東京+天気"
```

Then, this error occurs:

```
The file /Users/username/https:/google.co.jp/search?q=東京+天気 does not exist.
```

## What I tried

- If the query parameter (after `q=`) only includes alphabet (no Japanese), it works.

```
username@usernamenoAir ~ % open -a "Google Chrome" "https://google.co.jp/search?q=foo+bar"

% -> ok. Chrome browser launches and returns a search result.
```

- Japanese Character works properly in another situation like the following.

```
username@usernamenoAir ~ % echo 東京
東京
```

What is wrong?
Any information would be appreciated.

## Informations

I use zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0).

Comment: You need a way to percent encode characters, that's the keywords to look for.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my mac but if you use single quotes you get same behavior? (Running a bit newer version, `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`)

Comment: Why the heck would you tag this with "linux"?

Comment: Rerun `open -a "Google Chrome" "https://google.co.jp/search?q=東京+天気"` and make sure you get the error. Then remove `open -a "Google Chrome"` and run `od -x <<< "https://google.co.jp/search?q=東京+天気"`  and post result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: What version of macOS? It appears the `open` command is failing to recognize the input as a URL; I cannot reproduce this in macOS 13.4. You can try `open -u -a ...` as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string needs to be [URL encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP). Your query string should be converted to UTF-8 then URL encoded, resulting in a URL like this:

```
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC+%E5%A4%A9%E6%B0%97
```