# How to tell which characters will show nicely in the browser URL?

Tags: unicode

Which unicode characters will show up "nicely" in the browser URL bar?

- Invisible control characters won't show up.
- Combining characters/diacritics will be overlapping with the left, so should be stripped.
- Other stuff won't show up good?
- Chinese characters and Latin characters, and most script characters show up nice.

The question though is, how can you automatically figure this out from the [unicode data](https://unicode.org/ucd/)? Is there a category that should be stripped out from URL "slugs", some unicode property/value? If so, what should I be looking for? Or if it's not possible, that would be good to know, then I need to start considering some manual approaches.

The goal is to not strip out characters which will be visible nicely in the URL, but to strip out everything else.

Comment: It depends on the browser. Different browsers have different characters they consider safe to display in their decoded form in the address bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Comment: An interesting question, but a quick search of the [Unicode Standard 15.0](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/UnicodeStandard-15.0.pdf) shows no matches for _"URL"_, _"URI"_ or _"Uniform Resource"_. That suggests (though not conclusively) that no such _"unicode property/value"_ exists.

Comment: @BagusTesa OP is not looking for rules, but for _"some unicode property/value"_ which makes it a simple process to determine what data should be stripped out, without resorting to a "manual" rules based approach.