# What unicode characters are generally displayable across browsers (using system fonts) and not showing ਍ missing glyphs?

Tags: unicode, cross-platform

What is the minimal set of characters you can generally assume are supported across all browsers (in the URL bar, not using a custom font in a webpage).

For example, you can enter this in the browser just fine `https://example.com/©`. But some other symbols like some Chinese characters don't work. This chinese character works `/堿`, but this Chinese character doesn't for me `/`. So I'm wondering what the system level fonts across the major operating systems include in terms of support for unicode glyphs.

How can I figure that out?

I saw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font but not sure which platform supports which one, etc.. How can I figure that out do you think?

Comment: "all browsers" (in all OS) is a pretty large set ...

Comment: In general: https://www.w3.org/International/ but could depend on …, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ which translates to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%A3%93%84 or see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325676/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)